# Javascript - change "required" attribute after select checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have a  (with some form input) hidden by default.
If a select a checkbox, the  and its input will be show.

So, by default, the input text in the  must be "not required" (to complete the submit..) , but if I select the checkbox, How can I set the input text "required" ?!

```js
<script language="javascript">
function toggleFields() {
 var scelta = document.getElementById('mostraDiv');
 var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
 var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

 if (scelta.checked==true) {
  /* visualizzo e/o spengo i div che voglio */ 
  div1.style.display = "block";
  div2.style.display = "none";   
 }
 else {
  div1.style.display = "none";
  /* visualizzo e/o spengo i div che voglio */
  /* div2.style.display = "block"; */
 };
 
}
</script>
```

```html
<div>
show div1: <input type="checkbox" name="mostraDiv" id="mostraDiv" value="ok" onchange="toggleFields()" />
</div>


<form data-toggle="validator" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="gestionemenu" name="gestionemenu" action="elaboraForm.php" method="POST">
<div id="div1" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Mostro il DIV 1</h1>
    <input type ="text" class="form-control" name="campo1" />
</div>


<div id="div2" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Mostro il DIV 2</h1>
    <input type ="text" name="campo2" value="div2.." />
</div>

<div id="div n....">
 <h1>ALWAYS VISIBILE</h1>
 <input type ="text" name="campo3" value="div sempre visibile" />
</div>

<input type="submit" name="CONFIRM" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a requried attribute you can use `element.setAttribute('required','required');`
 and to remove it `element.removeAttribute('required');` where element would be the required input element.

Read more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

Answer (score 0):

You can do that when you select the input and set its attribute required, like this

`div1.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute('required', 'required');`

this will get the input in div with id `div1` and will set it to be required.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, please do not use Javascript to hide / display crucial elements of the page. This makes your page less accessible to those who choose to disable Javascript / have older browsers, etc. An acceptable solution would be to use CSS3 to hide / display the form sections, and add a simple text notice which will only display on legacy browsers, something like "This section is only required if you checked the box".

To answer your question, you can simply use something like:

```
function setRequiredFields(section, required) {
  for (var el of section.querySelectorAll("input")) {
    if (required) {
      el.setAttribute("required", "");
    } else {
      el.removeAttribute("required");
    }
  }
}
```

Then call as needed:

```
setRequiredFields(document.getElementById("div1"), true);
```

And finally, just to make sure – adding a "required" attribute adds virtually no security to your page (as it is the browsers' responsibility to enforce the requirements, or not).

Comment: ok, when can I read something about CSS3 and hide/show form section? Can You post me a link?!

Comment: @quattrocorde Here is a simple example: http://www.outofscope.com/css-only-menu-toggle-no-javascript-required/